# UIButton border color defaults to black. How can it be changed to the default ( blue ) color that is used for setting the title of the button text?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have created a UIButton:

```
testNavigationButton.setTitle("Test", forState: .Normal)
testNavigationButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
```

I tried to change the color to:

`testNavigationButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor().CGColor`

But the color of the border is different shade of blue than the default shade used for setting the title of the button. What is this shade and how can I change the color of border to this color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the color of the text using

```
let textColor = button.titleLabel?.textColor
```

And assign it to your borderColor like this:

```
button.layer.borderColor = textColor!.CGColor
```

Btw, from my test, the blue is `#007aff` you can initialise it using:

```
let color = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.478, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
```

---

**Update**

```
class MyButton: UIButton {

    private let normalColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.478, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    private let highlightedColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0.478, blue: 1, alpha: 0.3)

    override var highlighted: Bool {
        willSet {
            if newValue != highlighted {
                let anim = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderColor")
                anim.fromValue = newValue ? normalColor.CGColor : highlightedColor.CGColor
                anim.toValue = newValue ? highlightedColor.CGColor : normalColor.CGColor
                layer.borderColor = newValue ? highlightedColor.CGColor : normalColor.CGColor
                anim.duration = CATransaction.animationDuration()
                anim.timingFunction = CATransaction.animationTimingFunction()
                layer.addAnimation(anim, forKey: "MyButton.BorderColor")
            }
        }
    }
}
```